# Create task for dependency lock in Gradle >5.0

Tags: gradle, dependencies, gradlew

I want to create a task which to execute

> dependencies --update-locks '*:*'

I had a configuration:

```
dependencyLocking {
    lockAllConfigurations()
}
```

I try with

```
task lockDependencies {
    dependsOn = ['dependencies','--update-locks *:*']
}
```

But have:

> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':lockDependencies'.
>
>   > Task with path '--update-locks *:*' not found in root project

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass Gradle command line parameters as a task dependency, that's what your error above is about.

The state of writing locks, either with `--write-locks` or `--update-locks`, is something that happens really early in the build lifecycle.

You can somewhat control it from a task with the following:
* Create a placeholder task in your build script
* In the `settings.gradle(.kts)` query the requested tasks from the command line, and if it is there, mutate the start parameters:

```
if (startParameter.taskNames.contains('placeHolder')) {
    startParameter.setWriteDependencyLocks(true)
}
```

Note that this is not an option if you are trying to lock the classpath of the build itself, which is one of the motivations behind using a command line flag.

Note also that this just allows replacing a flag, like `--update-locks *:*` with a task invocation like `updateLocks` but will not work if that task is wired as a dependency of other tasks, as it needs to be requested explicitly. And doing the start parameter mutation *after* the task graph is computed is too late in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in my opinion is to add inside the build.gradle file the following code:

```
dependencyLocking {
    lockAllConfigurations()
}
task commitLockDependencies {
    'git add /gradle/dependency-locks '.execute()
}
init {
    dependsOn('commitLockDependencies')
}
```

And then inside the settings.gradle the following line:

```
startParameter.setWriteDependencyLocks(true)
```

Working with gradle 7.1.